# Would I have to add any additional weight at the end of the lever of well pump (B) for it to lift the same amount of water as did well pump (A)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, buoyancy

The question is if I would have to add any additional weight at the end of the lever of well pump (B) for it to lift the same amount of water as did well pump (A)?
My assumption is yes because of friction but really I'm very unsure!

Both wells have different dimensions but with the exact same amount of water (1000gallons), & the amount of water being lifted is also the same per lever stroke. The wells are drawn up as:

Well pump#A) 10x500x10

Pump piston at the bottom only lifts 5ft high and is
10x5x10 in both wells.

Well pump#B) 3x500x3

Pump piston at the bottom portion of the well is
10x5x10.

The friction I speak of will occur once water is being lifted from out of the bottom wider portion of the well which is (10x5x10) up into the smaller portion of Well#B which is (3x500x3)

EXTRA: The lever does move slowly. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for the not so accurate dimensional looking drawing haha.

Answer (score 0):

If the pistons are the same diameter, and the levers are the same, then the same weight will lift the same water. Lifting water through a smaller pipe will cause more restriction, not more weight, so the lever may move slower, but it will move. Think about it, if it did not move at all, there would be no friction to overcome.

Comment: Exactly the comment i was hoping for! The lever will not require more weight as it would only move a bit slower because of the "restriction" from moving water up into a smaller diameter pipe. Thank you!